# Create Java Application to run as a Windows Service

Tags: java, service, windows-services

i want to create a Windows Service which runs my Java-Application.

This was no problem by using

```
sc.exe create myService binPath= "java -jar C:\to\my\service.jar"
```

When I try to start my created service i get this response:

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
>   request in a timely fashion

Unfortunately it seems my Program didn't respond to the Windows Service that it is running.

How can I communicate to the Windows-Service that my Programm runs?

I tried [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) which worked great. But I don't want to use another thirdparty app.
When I searched for answers I always see that most people use [Java Service Wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/german/download.jsp).

How to structure my Java-Code to accept messages from the Windows-Services?

Here is i.e. a simple example of a time-printing programm which i want to run as a service. What do I have to do?

```
package tst;

import java.util.Date;

public class Tester
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long end = start + 20 * 1000;

                while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)
                {
                    Date date = new Date();
                    System.out.println("Time: " + date.toString());

                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I always see that most people use Java Service Wrapper"* If most people use that, it probably means you should too, so why don't you?

Comment: The problem is that i would need a licence but that is no option for me.

Comment: Did you try JavaExe? It is easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your application implements the interface required to interact with the [Windows Service Control Manager (SCM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685150(v=vs.85).aspx), you will not be able to start, stop or manipulate your application as a service. Your only option is to use a service wrapper like NSSM, JSW or even Microsoft's old but still functional [Srvany utility](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany).

Comment: Is there a predefined interface to implement to my class to support the SCM? Or how can I add that feature to my programm?

Comment: [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685942(v=vs.85).aspx) lists the functions that must be implemented by a Windows Service. Those functions are likely only available to Java through a native interface of some kind though...